# PHP convert sentence to array?

Tags: php, arrays

i have data return as below:

```
2015-07-2111
ali,21,malaysia
alan,23,england
```

my expected array:

```
0=>2015-07-2111
1=>ali,21,malaysia
2=>alan,23,england
```

my code :

```
$info = explode(",",$string);
```

But the code do not produce the array that i want.

Comment: `$info = explode(",",$string);` -> `$info = explode(PHP_EOL,$string);`

Comment: Why is this a comment and not an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're splitting it by `,` when you should be splitting it line by line, so change

```
$info = explode(",", $string);
//where $info becomes an array of "ali", "21", "malaysia\nalan", "23", "england"
```

to

```
$info = explode(PHP_EOL, $string);
//where $info becomes an array of "ali,21,malaysia", "alan,23,england"
```

as `PHP_EOL` is the "[correct 'End Of Line' symbol for this platform](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php)"

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$str =  "2015-07-2111
ali,21,malaysia
alan,23,england";

echo '<pre>';
print_r(explode("\n",$str));
```